# What is the relation between the thickness of a material and the pressure it can be exposed to, before reaching its ultimate tensile strength?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure

I was wondering whether there was a general relation or not, and as far I've read..:

1. It depends on the type of material – makes sense.
2. The thicker the material, the bigger the pressure it can be exposed to before bending or breaking – makes sense as well.

However, there was not an answer that directly stated the connection and I was hoping some of you could help sort this out for me.

Comment: Can you clarify what your experiment is? Are you pulling a rod of the material until it breaks and measuring the force needed to break it? If so, the force per unit area is called the breaking stress and is characteristic of the material.

Comment: Yes. 
I was trying to calculate when exactly the diameter of a wire made of stainless steel, would break when affected by constant force.


In other words; I'm conducting an experiment on the uniform circular motion, and wanted to find out when the centripedal force of an object with a known cross sectional area, moving at a constant velocity would exceed the breaking point.

Comment: So, your problem is, a thicker wire is stronger, but also heavier (hence more centripetal force)?